# Successive Detection Logarithmic Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, diodes, analog, power-measurement

let's consider this logarithmic Amplifier:

[image]

I do not understand why at the terminal LOG OUTPUT there is a current which is proportional to log(Vinput). The current flowing on each diode is equal proportional to exp(-qVouti/KT), where Vouti is the output voltage of each stage.

Each stage is a limiting amplifier: it has a transfer function like this one:

[image]

References: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-078.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text appears to indicate that current output is desired, so that summing is simpler.  I believe based on the text that the diodes are added to indicate a conversion to current output for the summation.  Note that it specifically states that "the detectors should be current outputs (not simple diodes)" indicating a linear voltage-to-current conversion.  If I'm right, I agree that it could have been explained/drawn better.